# Proving an existence of a cardinal when making assumptions on exponentiation

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let's assume $2^{\aleph_3}=\aleph_4$ and $\left(\aleph_{\omega_1}\right)^{\aleph_1}\neq\left(\aleph_{\omega_1}\right)^{\aleph_2}$.

Prove that $$\exists_{\alpha\in Lim}\left( \left(\aleph_{\alpha}\right)^{\aleph_2} > \aleph_{\omega_1}\ \wedge\ \forall_{\gamma <\alpha}\ \left(\aleph_{\gamma}\right)^{\aleph_2} \leq \aleph_{\omega_1}\right).$$

It's a question I found in one of the Set Theory exams at my Uni. To be honest, I have absolutely no idea where to start.

Could you give me a helping hand?

Comment: Is this an ongoing exam?

Comment: Hahah, no, thanks God no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since successor cardinals are regular, if $\kappa^+>\lambda$ then any function from $\lambda$ to $\kappa^+$ is bounded, thus ${}^\lambda\kappa^+=\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa^+}{}^\lambda\alpha$, and therefore
 $$ (\kappa^+)^\lambda\le\sum_{\alpha<\kappa^+}|\alpha|^\lambda=\kappa^+ \cdot\kappa^\lambda. $$
By the way, this arguments goes back to Hausdorff. Note that we in fact have $$(\kappa^+)^\lambda=\kappa^+\cdot\kappa^\lambda,$$ since the left hand side is obviously larger than or equal to the right hand side. Also, if $\kappa^+\le\lambda$, we also have equality since both sides equal $2^\lambda$.

In particular, if $\tau$ is a limit cardinal larger than $\kappa$, and $\kappa^\lambda\le\tau$, then also $(\kappa^+)^\lambda\le\tau$. It follows that the first $\mu$ such that $\mu^\lambda>\tau$ is either a limit cardinal or less than or equal to $\lambda$.

To apply the above to the case at hand, where $\tau=\aleph_{\omega_1}$ and $\lambda=\aleph_2$, note that the first of your assumptions ensures that if $\kappa^\lambda>\tau$, then $\kappa>\aleph_2$ since ${\aleph_2}^{\aleph_2}\le{\aleph_3}^{\aleph_3}=2^{\aleph_3}$.

Comment: But why should $\mu$ have a choice of being $\leq\lambda$?

Comment: For all we know, $2^\lambda$ is already larger than $\tau$. The equality $(\kappa^+)^\lambda=\kappa^+\cdot\kappa^\lambda$ says that either $\kappa^\lambda$ is already above $\tau$, or else, either $\kappa^+>\tau$ (which cannot be the case if $\tau$ is limit and larger than $\kappa$) or $(\kappa^+)^\lambda\le\tau$ as well. But the equality on its own does not rule out that $\kappa^\lambda$ is large for small $\kappa$, in which case we have no control over whether the least such $\kappa$ is limit or not. That's why we needed the last paragraph (and the first of your assumptions).

Comment: I think I don't follow your argument. We are trying to find conditions that satisfied will give us $\left(\kappa^+\right)^{\lambda} > \tau$ right? So, we rule out the first one because of the first assumption made by the question itself, the second one because of the reasons you stated, and are left with the third one, is that right? Doesn't that prove such $\alpha$ exists and is a limit ordinal? But we didn't use the second assumption of the question anywhere.

Comment: @Jules That is true. The second assumption is not needed.